# What is the best way to trim a json data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, trim

This is what I am currently doing to trim all of my value. It is ugly and a too repetitive.

```
var strHTML = '';
$.getJSON('info.php',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            strHTML += $.trim(item.fname) +
                       $.trim(item.lname) +
                       $.trim(item.address) +
                       $.trim(item.phone) +
                       ...(about 10 more of these);
        });
    });
```

There ought to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Is there no `$(item).each(function(j){ strHTML+= $.trim(this[j])}` ???

Comment: mplungjan doesn't work. I need the flexibly to concatenate my html along with this, but I left it out b/c of the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for...in` example, with [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
var obj = {
    foo: ' bar',
    blahblah: ' ahahaha   '
};

var arr = [];
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push($.trim(obj[key]));
    }
}
alert(arr.join(','));
```

Comment: Very close. How do I retain the obj name, e.g., arr.foo or arr.blahblah?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should trim the data on the PHP-side, as it's your PHP script that generates it <sup>1</sup>.

Basically : make sure your `info.php` script generates correct data.

In PHP, you can use the [**`trim()`**][1] function.

And if your data is stored in an array, you can apply that function to all items of that array using the [**`array_map()`**](https://www.php.net/array_map) function :

```
$data = array_map('trim', $data);
```

<sub>*As a consequence, I will add the PHP tag to this question*</sub>

Comment: Hi Martin, good advice, but I can't touch the server-side at this point which forced me to work on the clientside. It would be even better if the DB Admins trimmed the data in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all properties of item to be trimmed you can use the for (props in item) {} -loop to loop through all of them. Because u can use this on all javascript-object you can create a function that does the trimming on all properties of an object.